# add an instance declaration haskell

Tags: list, haskell

This is my function:

```
    bestLocByArtiest :: String -> [Review] -> Double
    bestLocByArtiest art = rev
        where gmloc = [gemZaalByArtiest art, gemFestByArtiest art, gemOpenByArtiest art]
              rev = max gmloc
```

This is the error i get:

```
    Review.hs:101:24:
Couldn't match type `[Review] -> Double' with `Review'
Expected type: [Review] -> Double
  Actual type: [[Review] -> Double] -> [[Review] -> Double]
In the expression: rev
In an equation for `bestLocByArtiest':
    bestLocByArtiest art
      = rev
      where
          gmloc = [gemZaalByArtiest art, ....]
          rev = max gmloc
```

So I was hoping somebody could explain me what this error means and what I have to change in my code to solve it.

**EDIT**
By changing max to maximum i got this new error:

```
    Review.hs:103:21:
No instance for (Ord ([Review] -> Double))
  arising from a use of `maximum'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (Ord ([Review] -> Double))
In the expression: maximum gmloc
In an equation for `rev': rev = maximum gmloc
In an equation for `bestLocByArtiest':
    bestLocByArtiest art
      = rev
      where
          gmloc = [gemZaalByArtiest art, ....]
          rev = maximum gmloc
```

What does this mean?

Comment: `max` does maximum of two, not of a list of N elements.  You want `maximum`.  Also, you don't seem to be accepting your second argument (the `[Review]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `bestLocByArtiest` is called with a `String` the type of `rev` needs to be `[Review] -> Double`. However it's actually `[[Review] -> Double] -> [[Review] -> Double]`. That's basically what the error message says.

So to fix it you either need to change the type signature of `bestLocByArtiest` or you need to modify what `rev` does. That involves looking at the types of `max`, `gmloc` and the individual elements in `gmloc` to make sure it does what you want.